# Design pattern to choose proper constants value

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a set of Key and Value pairs. Based on the operating system I have to change the value of the keys. Currently I have put all the key-values in different property file and based on the operating system I load appropriate file. Wanted to know if I am doing it correctly or else is there another way to do everything in programming language, (not taking variables from config file). Can I mandate the coder to create all the constants similar to methods in interface?

Comment: Your question is too generic. What programming language are you using?

Comment: Tag it then!!!!

Comment: Can you please explain more.. I didnt get it

Comment: What kind of configuration are you referring to? Can you give examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configurations stored in property files are always better than those put in code. They are more maintainable and making changes in future is simpler. So, your design is good as is.

Additionally, you can also move common configurations, which will be same for all operating systems, to one file so as to minimize code duplication.